# woocommcerce create proruct error 401, why?

Tags: curl, woocommerce, product

i try to add a new product in my woocommcerce shop with curl. Creating categories are working fine, but if i tr< to add a new product i get this error:

"{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_create","message":"Entschuldigung, du hast keine Berechtigung, um Ressourcen zu erstellen.","data":{"status":401}}"

Looks like no authentication. So i am unauthorized, but why? My User is admin with read/write premissions. May side is https and i send comsumer key and secret like i do with the categories.

```
curl -X POST https://jmyshop.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products \ -u 47110815:1122334455 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"BROMBEER-SCHW. RIBISEL PASS. 45% DARBO 5 KG","type":"simple","regular_price":"22.90","description":"<BESCHREIBUNG>","short_description":"<KURZBESCHREIBUNG>","sku":"00331","featured":false,"stock_status":"outofstock","weight":"5","catalog_visibility":"visible","categories": [{}],"images": [{}]}' >rmtmp/X.ART.WOO.NEU.20230620112025.OUT
```

SO why does it not work?